# Fetch an entire object with attributes from another objects

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, core-data, nsfetchrequest

I want to fetch an object Person, but in this person object I have an different ID's. Here is a screenshot to my database. Like you can see I have a company-id,department-id and function-id. Now I want to fetch that person object, but instead of the company,department and function-ids, I want their names.

Should I make for each object a separate request? Or can this be done in another way?
[image]

**EDIT**

Oké at the moment I'm fetching like this.

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchPerson = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Data"];
    NSSortDescriptor *descriptorPerson = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"text" ascending:NO];
    fetchPerson.sortDescriptors = @[descriptorPerson];

    NSArray *matches = [[RKManagedObjectStore defaultStore].mainQueueManagedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchPerson error:nil];
   Data *data= [matches objectAtIndex:0];
    person = data.person;
    Company *company = data.company;
    Department *department = data.department;
    Function *function = data.function;
```

This is only getting the data that is inside the Data-object but person,compayn,department,function objects are empty.

When I do a fetchrequest on the Person entity. I got only the data back from the person object.

Comment: If you're using CoreData you shouldn't have to even worry about IDs, just make a relationship between a person and a company object. CoreData handles the internals.

Comment: Also, you seem to have created the data table as a relationship table (potentially for many-to-many?) just add a "department" relationship to person and use that instead.

Comment: @Fogmeister I've edited my post. could you please take a look at it.

Comment: I'm not sure what isn't showing when you say it isn't showing up anything.

Comment: When I do a fetch on the person entity for example I got only the person object.